# How change emmeted value BehaviourSubject?

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, behaviorsubject

everyone!
I need clear emmeted  value, example Simple BehaviorSubject:
In template I have:

```
{{box}}

//==///

box.subscribe();

box.next(100);// box show 100

if(a==5){ box.next(500);}// box changed on 500, show 500
```

Need in template of component change value box.
Was 100, if a becom 5, 100 need change on 500.

How it can do?

Comment: `{{ box | async }}`

Answer (score 1):

doing `box.subscribe();` won't do anything. you have to do something with the subscription.

```
boxValue = 0:

ngOnInit(){
  this.box.subscribe(res => {
    console.log('got a value: ', res);
    this.boxValue = res; // listen to the box subscription and do something
  });
}
```

then in the template you can do: {{boxValue}}.

subscribing in the .ts file is a bad practice, so instead just delete `box.subscribe();` and use the async pipe: https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe

```html
<h1> The box value: {{ box | async }} </h1>
```